# Magento admin taking too much time to save product in admin

Tags: admin, mysql, products-management, enterprise-1.14

Whenever am trying to save a product in admin magento is taking too much time and some times throws sql error like below.This is Enterprise edition 1.14.2 upgraded from EE 1.9. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '17132-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO
>   `catalog_product_index_price_tmp` SELECT
>   `catalog_product_index_price`.* FROM `catalog_product_index_price`
>   WHERE (entity_id IN('4458', '14873', '14874', '14875', '14876',
>   '14877', '14878', '14879', '17132', '17133', '17134', '17135',
>   '17136', '17137', '17138', '17139', '17140', '17141', '17142',
>   '17143', '17144', '29076', '29077', '29078', '29079', '29080',
>   '29814', '29815', '29816', '37208', '37209', '37210', '37211',
>   '37212', '37213', '37214', '37215', '37216', '37217', '37218',
>   '37219', '37732', '37733', '37734', '44734', '44735', '44736',
>   '44737', '44738', '44739', '44740', '44741', '44742', '44743',
>   '44744', '44745', '44746', '44747', '44748', '44749', '44750',
>   '44751', '44752', '44753', '44754', '44755', '45026', '45027',
>   '45028', '53678', '53679', '53680', '53681', '53682', '53683',
>   '53684', '112446'))

Comment: Did this error ever came back ? I followed the accepted answer but the problem happened later on again.

Comment: it did not came back..one more additional thing i did is to change few of indexing to Manual instead of automatic. May be this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two things that dictate store performance,

1. Code quality
2. Hosting

You can rule out the first part by disabling all your third party modules. You can rule out the latter by testing your store with another host.

---

If you want to fix the symptom alone, set your indexes to be "Update on Schedule" - and you'll see an improvement in product save time.

Regarding your SQL error, I'd be inclined to truncate `catalog_product_index_price` and re-index price and re-apply all promo rules.

Comment: Thank you so much,i have truncated catalog_product_index_price  and core_url_rewrite table and re-indexed.so far its working fine.Not sure why i have to truncate catalog_product_index_price but its working. thanks again